# jest supertest with express-session

Tags: node.js, express, session, jestjs, supertest

I want to test my routes with jest but I don't know how to mock or simulate a session in my test to pass the first if line 2

```js
app.get('/getMailSuiviList', (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.infoUser != undefined) {
        let mail = require('../models/M_Email')
        mail.indexSuiviByDept(req.session.infoUser.deptID)
            .then(dataMails => {
                res.json(dataMails)
            })
            .catch(e => {
                res.json('Erreur: ' + e)
            })
    } else {
        req.session.error = 'Vous devez vous connecter'
        res.redirect('/')
    }
})
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you haven't, check supertest-session package, it's a wrapper around supertest and provides session auth in requests:

[supertest-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest-session)

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Comment: i tried to use supertest-session but the problem is when i try to set the informations session on req.session.infoUser i have the error : Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'infoUser')